# Tailwind divide color only for divide-x

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is it possible to make `divide-gray-600` only apply to `divide-x`? It seems like there's no `divide-x-gray-600` option. See how I'm trying to make the second item have red border bottom:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex items-stretch w-full divide-x divide-gray-600 text-center bg-gray-100">
  <div class="flex-1 border-b border-red-600 p-2">Red border bottom</div>
  <div class="flex-1 border-b border-red-600 p-2">Should have red border bottom</div>
  <div class="flex-1 border-b border-gray-600 p-2">Gray border bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [per-side border colors](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/4404) are coming soon to Tailwind if you're using the JIT compilation mode. I'm not sure when it will be released, so as of me writing this, per-side border colors are not available. When they do become available, you can fix your issue by applying the `border-b-red-600` on the middle div. (This won't work if you're using the [CDN installation method](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-via-cdn).)

**UPDATE:** Per-side border colors are now available in [TailwindCSS v2.2](https://blog.tailwindcss.com/tailwindcss-2-2)!

In the meantime, or if you're not using JIT, you can write your own [border-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) utilities or your own `divide` utilities.

```css
.divide-x-gray-600 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
    --tw-divide-opacity: 1;
    border-right-color: rgba(75,85,99,var(--tw-divide-opacity));
    border-left-color: rgba(75,85,99,var(--tw-divide-opacity));
}
```

This isn't very "Tailwind-y", but it should work. If you want to do things in a more "Tailwind" way, you can also [write a plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-utilities) that generates them for you. Keep in mind that if you're not using JIT, you may end up with an even more massive unpurged CSS file since you're generating two more sets of utilities for each color.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a second div inside the first one. What’s the downvote for btw?

Comment: Boom, included in v2.2! :)

Comment: But it looks like it's still not overruling the divide-color. Hm. Maybe need to skip using divide and set side border colors on each child element instead. Can anyone think of another workaround?